# Openvswitch / KVM Guest unable to ping external GW

Tags: networking, kvm, rhel6, openvswitch, vlan

I've got a host with RHEL6.4 OS. Under the host I have a KVM VM also running RHEL6.4.

The host is connected to tagged switch interface that has vlan tag 1.

I've configured the host network interfaces as follows:

ifcfg-eth0

#

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

#

ifcfg-eth1

#

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

#

ifcfg-bond0

#

```
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup primary=eth0 miimon=100"
```

#

and the host vswitch as follows:

#

```
ovs-vsctl add-br ovsbr0
ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 bond0
ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 vlan1 tag=1 -- set interface content type=internal
ifconfig vlan1 192.168.1.2/28 up
```

#

And I'm able to ping the external vlan1 GW(192.168.1.1).

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to ping external IPv4 Gateway from the VM.
When I ping from the VM, I get response for the first packet, but the rest seem to lose the VLAN tag and goes to wrong interface.
If I tcpdump bond0.1 I see the first ICMP request and reply, but the rest of the ICMP replys seem to appear on bond0 interface (not bond0.1)

#

```
[root@vm ~]# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.64 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 1 received, 80% packet loss, time 4786ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.642/2.642/2.642/0.000 ms
[root@vm ~]#
```

#

```
[root@vm ~]#  tcpdump -i bond0.1 host 192.168.1.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bond0.1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
20:49:28.053502 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 1, length 64
20:49:28.054158 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP echo reply, id 55664, seq 1, length 64
20:49:29.055189 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 2, length 64
20:49:30.054971 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 3, length 64
20:49:31.054935 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 4, length 64
20:49:32.054918 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 5, length 64
```

#

```
[root@vm]# tcpdump -i bond0 host 192.168.1.1
tcpdump: WARNING: bond0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bond0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
20:49:28.053509 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 1, length 64
20:49:29.055199 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 2, length 64
20:49:29.055653 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP echo reply, id 55664, seq 2, length 64
20:49:30.054983 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 3, length 64
20:49:30.055522 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP echo reply, id 55664, seq 3, length 64
20:49:31.054968 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 4, length 64
20:49:31.056497 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP echo reply, id 55664, seq 4, length 64
20:49:32.054927 IP 192.168.1.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 55664, seq 5, length 64
20:49:32.055402 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP echo reply, id 55664, seq 5, length 64
```

The VM network interfaces are configured as follows:

ifcfg-eth0

#

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

ifcfg-eth1

#

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

ifcfg-bond0

#

```
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME=bond1
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup primary=eth0 miimon=100"
```

ifcfg-bond0.1

#

```
VLAN=yes
TYPE=Vlan
DEVICE=bond0.1
NAME=bond0.1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
```

Any idea why this issue occurs?

Answer (score 0):

By default Vlan 1 is untagged. So When you are using it as tagged(port in trunk mode) you should choose on a switch the another untagged (default vlan).
On wrong vlan configuration you might see the above behavior: you are sending the traffic but you aren't getting it back.
So create another vlan and try again.

Also check sysctl and another setting with [this article](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/KVM_with_bonding_and_VLAN_tagging_setup_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html)